# Treat .mdb as .xlsx?

Tags: excel, ms-access, xlsx

I recently made an Excel workbook (with the help of Stackoverflow) where I have a regular input of data (each entry is one row with different columns). I then have a macro that extracts the data from a specified row to a different sheet and saves this sheet as a .PDF.

That way, I can extract specific data from this Excel "database" to a readable pdf. I do this because I need a paper version from specific entries.

For a different project I need to implement the same principle. The only difference is that I need to work with an .mdb file where the data is stored, instead of an Excel workbook.

Is there a way I can reuse my code from Excel or is it now a completely different story?

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you can remove Excel totally from the equation thats great. In MS Access you can create a report off your data (with no programming) and you can probably export that as PDF (probably with a little programming... possibly just in a macro). Use your Excel learnings to start afresh. Don't copy and paste your existing code, build fresh new code based on what you've learnt

Comment: How to save an MS Access report as PDF (in a macro without programming): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf5dc54a-9c39-42e7-a175-2984825a60be/access-2007-save-as-pdf-from-vba-automation?forum=isvvba

Answer (score 1):

You can link your excel workbook to your Access tables. On the "DATA" ribbon there is a section for "External Data".

Once you've got the Access data displayed on one of your worksheets, you should be able to adapt your existing code accordingly.

From Microsoft:
[Connect an Access database to your workbook](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Connect-an-Access-database-to-your-workbook-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525)